# How do I know if "npm install" finished (successful or error) via code?

Tags: php, laravel, npm

It's rather simple to execute commands via `exec("npm install")` but how would I be able to differentiate how and when it finishes?

Comment: It should tell you when it finishes, if it was successful or if there was an error.
If npm never finishes and gives you a prompt, npm has not finished, or is hung up.
Do you have a specific module you are installing, or a screenshot of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add the [loglevel](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel) config arg to your command...